# The imageView inside a popup window doesnot update after user interaction.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, popupwindow

[image: A popup Example we use for one of the screens]

I have created a custom popup view that can be used to set a priority level. Initially, when I try to set display the popup, I preset the `ImageView` with `ImageView.pressed(true)`, which is shown by the grayed out background of the images.

Now when I click on another image, i am able to register the click but unable to display the changes onto the screen, i.e., unable to simulate the `ImageView.Pressed(true)` state onto the image that is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

For this same purpose, I use `ImageButton`s, and have a method for setting state for a group of related buttons that is called from the `onClick()` listener.  E.g.,

```
private void configurePaletteStrokeWidth(Crayon.StrokeWidth strokeWidth) {
    findViewById(R.id.iButtonStrokeWidthSmall).setSelected(false);
    findViewById(R.id.iButtonStrokeWidthMedium).setSelected(false);
    findViewById(R.id.iButtonStrokeWidthLarge).setSelected(false);
    findViewById(R.id.iButtonStrokeWidthXLarge).setSelected(false);
    switch (strokeWidth) {
    case SMALL:
        findViewById(R.id.iButtonStrokeWidthSmall).setSelected(true);
        break;
    case LARGE:
        findViewById(R.id.iButtonStrokeWidthLarge).setSelected(true);
        break;
    case XLARGE:
        findViewById(R.id.iButtonStrokeWidthXLarge).setSelected(true);
        break;
    case MEDIUM:
        findViewById(R.id.iButtonStrokeWidthMedium).setSelected(true);
        break;
    }
}
```

The xml for each of the buttons is similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_stroke_width_small_tap" android:state_pressed="true"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_stroke_width_small_tap" android:state_selected="true"/> <!-- selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_stroke_width_small_normal" android:state_focused="true"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_stroke_width_small_normal"/> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

Comment: thanks. but my implementation uses a dynamic addition of ImageButton/ImageViews into a LinearLayout. so the setPressed(ture/false) only works with ImageButton as in the same manner as the ImageView. and I add drawables also dynamically so the Selector cannot be implemented but what i do is i set background with one such selector implementation. But even with a ImageButton implementation the button cannot be set accordingly.